# How can I get the Unit Number to be displayed in place of the "ID"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I write a SQL query that will replace the "ComputerID" and "PartID" with the "UnitNumber". The ComputerID's and PartID's are in the same column under InventoryID. The InventoryID's are unique but the UnitNumber (sticker label/name) doesn't have this requirement.

Here are the tables and how they relate.
[image]

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question, What is your sample data and what is your desire result. What have you try. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The sample data are the two tables on the left. The result table is under the "Result" label.

Comment: I didnt catch the result because in your table `4797` has UnitNumber `000047` but in your result show `000286`

Comment: Uh oh, I apologize for that mess up. Thank you for that catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your tables `Object` and `Inventory`

If you use a couple of joins then this should work:

```
select o.ObjectID as ObjectID, a.UnitNumber as Computer, b.UnitNumber as Part,
o.InputID from Object o 
join Inventory a on a.InventoryID=o.CombputerID 
join Inventory b on b.InventoryID=o.PartID
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. On your last line I had to change b.PartID to o.PartID

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Just remember that if you need other columns from the `Inventory` table you'll have to specify which instance you want as it is joined twice.